# append serialized data to url

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using a flight search api. My question is in my form, if I send the form fields to an ajax file as

```
var data = $('form').serialize();
```

Is there a way in my ajax file to append serialize() string sent to my api url. Right now my ajax file looks like this and although it works, it is very messy and code needs refactored:

```
require('lib/Unirest.php'); 

if(isset($_POST['departureAirport'])){
    $customerSessionId = $_POST['customerSessionId'];
    $departureAirport = $_POST['departureAirport'];
    $destinationAirport = $_POST['destinationAirport'];
    $departureDate = $_POST['departureDate'];
    $returnDate = $_POST['returnDate'];
    $adults = $_POST['adults'];





$getdata = Unirest::get("http://test.api.theapidomain.com/airticket/v1/list.aspx?cid=N7Y5C1&customerSessionId=".$customerSessionId."&departureAirport=".$departureAirport."&destinationAirport=".$destinationAirport."&departureDate=".$departureDate."&returnDate=".$returnDate."&adults=".$adults."", array( "Accept" => "application/json" )
);
```

I was really hoping for something like this:

```
$dataSent = //the serialized data sent
$getdata = Unirest::get("http://test.api.theapidomain.com/airticket/v1/list.aspx? + $dataSent, array( "Accept" => "application/json" )
    );
```

here is my jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('#myform').submit(function(e){
         e.preventDefault();   
        var data = $('form').serialize(); 
        $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "ajax.php",  
            data: data,
            success: function(response){
            $("#result").html(response);
            }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send your form data as a string

**Javascript**

```
$('#myform').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();   
    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "ajax.php",  
        data: {data: $('form').serialize()},
        success: function(response){
            $("#result").html(response);
        }
});
```

Or simplified using `$.post()`

```
$('#myform').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();   
    $.post("ajax.php", {data: $('form').serialize()}, function(response){
        $("#result").html(response);
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
$dataSent = isset($_POST['data']) ? $_POST['data'] : NULL
$getdata = Unirest::get("http://test.api.theapidomain.com/airticket/v1/list.aspx?" . $dataSent, array( "Accept" => "application/json" ));
```

Comment: Koalo wow that first line is so condensed i am not sure what is going on...i guess i am to new. How would this fit into my jquery above?

Comment: @smitty That part does not go in your ajax file but in your javascript code where you make the call, the only difference is that instead of sending the data parameter as a serialized string, you send an object with your data as a string, how about you update your question with your javascript code so I can point out exactly how you need to change it

Comment: updating now...sorry too many hours...i think i need a break.

Comment: now i see it...just wrap in {} to make it object with data as string. Thank you so much!

Comment: @koalo is there any good way to loop through returned data and format and display only things you want?

Comment: @smitty you mean after getting the results from your API? It seems you're getting a json object as the response so you can use `json_decode($getdata)` in php and create a view looping through the items and formatting/displaying the values that you need

Answer (score 0):

```
$dataSent = file_get_contents('php://input');

$getdata = Unirest::get("http://test.api.theapidomain.com/airticket/v1/list.aspx?".$dataSent, array( "Accept" => "application/json" )
    );
```

But it's not safe

Comment: Yes. You've written it in your question post.